# PHP separated baseurl from upload url

Tags: php

My upload URL Is:

```
http://localhost/user/uploads/files/1/thumbs/1/video/IMG45.jpg
```

I need to seve this url in database without base url like this :

```
uploads/files/1/thumbs/1/video/IMG45.jpg
```

How do can I separated this ?

Comment: do you have baseurl value in variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url = 'http://localhost/user/uploads/files/1/thumbs/1/video/IMG45.jpg';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // "/user/uploads/files/1/thumbs/1/video/IMG45.jpg"
```

// edit

Ah, didn't notice the first part of the path that needs to be stripped out as well... You can check for and strip the user part from it like this:

```
$base_path = '/user';
if(substr($path, 0, strlen($base_path)) == $base_path) {
    $path = substr($path, strlen($base_path));
}
```

Comment: `/user/` is subfolder(subdomain in localhost) I need to separate this!

Answer (score 0):

Using explode function(**i.e., Split a string by string**), you can able to save the url in DB without base url.

```
$image_name = "your url"; // pass the url here
$img_url = explode('/',$image_name);
$img_nam =$img_url[4].'/'.$img_url[5];
```

*pass **$img_nam** variable in database using insert query.*

Hope it may help you...